# Select the first row in the last group of consecutive rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

How would I select the row that is the first occurrence in the last 'grouping' of consecutive rows, where a grouping is defined by the consecutive appearance of a particular column value (in the example below `state`).

For example, given the following table:

| id | datetime | state | value_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 09:42:41.319000 | incomplete | A |
| 2 | 2021-04-04 09:42:41.319000 | done | B |
| 3 | 2021-04-05 09:42:41.319000 | incomplete | C |
| 4 | 2021-04-05 10:42:41.319000 | incomplete | C |
| 5 | 2021-04-07 09:42:41.319000 | done | D |
| 6 | 2021-04-012 09:42:41.319000 | done | E |

I would want the row with `id=5` as it it is the first occurrence of `state=done` in the last (i.e. most recent) grouping of `state=done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all columns `NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl t2
   WHERE  t2.state <> t1.state
   AND    t2.datetime > t1.datetime
   )
ORDER  BY datetime
LIMIT  1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bc0147adb092853c7c7bedba71dc7bf1)*

`NOT EXISTS` is only true for the last group of peers. (There is no later row with a different state.)
`ORDER BY datetime` and take the first. Voilá.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a window function solution that accesses your table only once (which may or may not perform better for large data sets):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    LEAD (state) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) 
      IS DISTINCT FROM state AS first_in_group
  FROM tbl
) t
WHERE first_in_group
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

A [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=89cd30cdcf9bae23117cfad98f2c94e6) based on [Erwin Brandstetter's](http://Erwin%20Brandstetter). To illustrate, here's the value of `first_in_group` for each row:

```
id  datetime                 state       value_needed  first_in_group
---------------------------------------------------------------------
6   2021-04-12 09:42:41.319  done        E             f
5   2021-04-07 09:42:41.319  done        D             t
4   2021-04-05 10:42:41.319  incomplete  C             f
3   2021-04-05 09:42:41.319  incomplete  C             t
2   2021-04-04 09:42:41.319  done        B             t
1   2021-04-01 09:42:41.319  incomplete  A             t
```